# How to detect if an SVG link has errors in Python

Tags: python, svg, python-requests

Making a simple `requests.get('https://svgur.com/i/NnM.svg').text` returns the content of the SVG but not the errors.

[image]

Is there a way to detect errors in an SVG link using Python?

Comment: parse it with an XML parser and see what errors the XML parser gives you.

Comment: Parsing isn't the issue, my problem is to get the error in the response of my request and not just the SVG.

Comment: And that's precisely what an XML parser will tell you. The screenshot looks like a browser XML parser error, that's got nothing to do with python.

Comment: So I would need to use a web driver (e.g. Selenium)?

Comment: I don't see why that would have anything to do with your problem either.